# What is the best practice to authenticate with Windows Authentication but Authorize using a custom database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I would like to authenticate users using Windows authentication as this would be an intranet site. However, I would like to authorize users based on my own authorization rules that I will set up in a database. I do not want to use roles in AD to define groups for authorization and will have my own custom authorization rules.

My plan is to create an extension of the AuthorizeAttribute and have checks implemented by overriding the AuthorizeCore() method to do additional checks.

Are there better methods and recommendations to implement the above?

I will be using MVC 5 and in the near future upgrading this to MVC 6.

Comment: This is how it is commonly done for your scenario. I've seen systems authenticated via AD (why reinvent the wheel) and authorized via app specific roles/permissions before for MVC and WebApi.

Comment: Hi Samuel, are you talking about authentication or authorization? you can do this with authentication through AD and use your authorization with custom roles thats provide while Authorize attribute. also you can write custom module to handle this before your request pass through controller.